# Consume only data i need in Task - Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 streams each for 3 different tables that are loaded batch once per day. Perhaps any day one of the tables doesn't load any data but the others yes.

I have a task that is triggered when all 3 streams have data and with a cursor and a for loops over each process date (column), and triggers a stored procedure ONLY if in the 3 streams there is data on that same process date.

All that is working fine, but the problem is in the case when for one date there is data for each stream but for another date theres data for only two of the streams. The thing is that when de SP is called, the data for the process date that is in the 3 streams is loaded in the final table (with a merge into) and the data for the other process date that is only present in two of the streams isn't, BUT the data of the 3 streams is deleted!

How can i resolve this? Copying the info of the streams in a persistent table and working with this ones? I was hopping that streams has a feature that i wasn't aware of.

Detailed above in the post

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is not data in all 3 tables for a specific date? Why can’t the code in your SP be written to cater for all the possible scenarios of which tables contain data for a given date?

Comment: Hi Nick, if the data is not available por all the dependencies, that process date of data doesn't have to be processed (in the final table). I can't be looking for new data in the raw data because those tables have all the history. I need to analyze only new data (thats why i'm using streams). And then i need to process final table only when all the dependencies are available, but the question is oriented in the case of one of the dependencies have multiple dates of data to be process but other dependencies have less data.